# while infinite loop in octave

Tags: while-loop, octave

I am writing a code to convert from decimal number to binary number without using library method. But using while loop. It seems it is stuck in a infinite loop.

In debugger mode I tried to see what is the value of `x`. But even when the value of `x` gets to 0 or 1, while loop does not exit. Is it a bug in octave or even Matlab has this problem (I don't have Matlab or in any position to use it)?

```
function ans = dec2bin(input)
  x = int16(input);
  y = [];
  while (x!=1) || (x!=0)
    y=[mod(x,int16(2)) y];
    x=idivide(x,int16(2));    
  end
  y=[mod(x,int16(2)) y];
  ans = arrayfun(@(a) mat2str(a) ,y);
end
```

Comment: You are asking for `x` being different from 1 **or** being different from 0. This is always true! If `x==1`, it will be different from 0. If `x==0`, it will be different from 1. Try `(x!=1)&&(x!=0)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `(x!=1) || (x!=0)` will always be true - if x is 1 it's not equal to 0, and vise-versa. You should use an `&&` logical condition, not an `||`:

```
while (x!=1) && (x!=0)
```